# java: Extract a substring using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have String data in which I am interested to extract a substring but I am stuck on creating the regex pattern for that.The String data I have is following:

```
$.ajax({url:"Q" + "uestions?" 
                + "" + "action=" 
                + "maxim" + "um&" 
                + "p043366329446409=08315891235072667&" 
                + "c" + "ity=" 
                + k.val() + "&" 
                + e + "=888",success:succFun,error:errFun,async:false});
        };
```

I want to extract `p043366329446409=08315891235072667` part from the above string.This data changes everytime I make request to server but `"p0"` will always start the string and `&"` will end the string.

Thanks EveryOne.

Comment: You are making it as a string by so many concatenation. Why you can't directly use it?

Comment: @ling.s I am getting this data from a server, so I can't directly use it.I can only use regex.

Comment: Is query param key 'p043366329446409' always constant?

Comment: @Braj no it's not a constant.It changes everytime we request data.

Comment: It means other values are constant and you need only dynamic value in this string?

Comment: @Braj yes you are correct.

Comment: Use regex like this "p0([0-9]+)=([0-9]+)&"

Comment: The string to be extract it's always the third ?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno  I didn't get you.What do you mean by third?

Comment: Its always the third passed argument?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Yes it's always third.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
String mydata = "<query string>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("p0([0-9]+)=([0-9]+)&");  

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
int start=0,end=0; 
if(matcher.find())
{
   start=matcher.start();
   end=matcher.end();

   System.out.println(mydata.substring(start,end-1));
}
```

Comment: Your code is just giving me the first part of the string and not after the "=" operator.

Comment: why did you use while loop?

Comment: If there are more than one occurrences of this type of parameters.

Comment: You can find start and end index of matched string and then use substring method to find the desired output.

Comment: Thanks Braj for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String p0 = s.replaceAll(".*&(p0.+?=.+?)&.*", "$1");
```

Comment: I just made an edit to my question to inform that nothing is constant in the string, so we can't assume string will start with p043366329446409.Sorry for that.

Comment: What are you using s.replaceAll() ?How would this return me the required value?

Comment: in this case it does not replace but returns contents of group 1 - expression in round brackets, try it

Comment: this    String s = "uestions?action=maximum&p043366329446409=08315891235072667&city="; 
   String p0 = s.replaceAll(".*&(p0.+?=.+?)&.*", "$1");
   System.out.println(p0);
works fine for me